# JS Question regarding compare date using 2 functions

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm very novice at Javascript so apologies for asking naff questions.
This piece of code is returning a Nan when it should retrieve days elapsed.
Is the second function causing the issue?

Here it is:

```
<body>
  <script>
    function elapsedTime(date1, date2) {
      var start = new Date(date1);
      var startMilli = start.getTime();

      var end = new Date(date2);
      var endMilli = end.getTime();

      var elapsed = (endMilli - startMilli);
      alert(millisToDaysHoursMinutes(elapsed));

    }
    function millisToDaysHoursMinutes(millis) {
      var seconds = millis / 1000;
      var totalMinutes = seconds / 60;
      var minutesPerDay = 60 * 24;
      var days  = totalMinutes / minutesPerDay;

      return days;
    }
  </script>
  <form>
    Start:<input type="text" name="date1" value="dd/m/year" /><br>
    End:  <input type="text" name="date2" value="dd/m/year" />
    <input type="button" name="button1" onclick="elapsedTime(date1.value, date2.value)" value="Get Elapsed Time" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you not using `<input type="date">`?

Comment: You are suggesting `dd/m/year` format to the user, but be aware that dates in that format are interpreted as `m/d/y` when passed to `new Date`.

Comment: With dates as `13/10/1992 (dd/m/year)`, `var start = new Date(date1);` will return null, and the rest is meaningless. May be an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the dates entered are valid else you'll get a `NaN` (Not a Number). Use `input type=date` and make them `required` then you can easily check that they're valid before calling your date diff function.

EG:

```js
function elapsedTime(date1, date2) {
  var start = new Date(date1);
  var startMilli = start.getTime();

  var end = new Date(date2);
  var endMilli = end.getTime();

  var elapsed = (endMilli - startMilli);
  alert(millisToDaysHoursMinutes(elapsed));

}

function millisToDaysHoursMinutes(millis) {
  var seconds = millis / 1000;
  var totalMinutes = seconds / 60;
  var minutesPerDay = 60 * 24;
  var days = totalMinutes / minutesPerDay;

  return days;
}
var date1 = document.querySelector("input[name=date1]"),
  date2 = document.querySelector("input[name=date2]"),
  button1 = document.querySelector("input[name=button1]");

button1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var date1valid = date1.checkValidity();
  var date2valid = date2.checkValidity();
  if (date1valid && date2valid) {
    elapsedTime(date1.value, date2.value);
  } else {
    alert("Please provide both dates!");
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  Start:<input type="date" name="date1" required="required" value="dd/m/year" /><br> End: <input type="date" name="date2" required="required" value="dd/m/year" />
  <input type="button" name="button1" value="Get Elapsed Time" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use input type `date` to make your code work:

```html
<form>
    Start:<input type="date" name="date1" /><br>
    End:  <input type="date" name="date2" />
          <input type="button" name="button1" onclick="elapsedTime(date1.value, date2.value)" value="Get Elapsed Time" />
</form>
```